# Why does this payable address fail to transfer funds?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, remix

```
contract MyContract {
  address payable public owner;
  address payable public withdrawAddress = 0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2; 
  
  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    ...
  }

  function totalBalance() external view returns(uint) {
    // CAST CONTRACT TO PAYABLE ADDRESS
    return payable(address(this)).balance;
  }

  function withdrawFunds() external withdrawAddressOnly() {
    msg.sender.transfer(this.totalBalance());
  }

  modifier withdrawAddressOnly() {
    require(msg.sender == withdrawAddress, 'only withdrawer can call this');
    _;
  }
  
  ...
```

```
contract MyContract {
  address payable public owner;
  address payable public withdrawAddress = 0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2; 
  
  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    ...
  }

  function totalBalance() external view returns(uint) {
    // PAYABLE ADDRESS SET ABOVE
    return owner.balance;
  }

  function withdrawFunds() external withdrawAddressOnly() {
    msg.sender.transfer(this.totalBalance());
  }

  modifier withdrawAddressOnly() {
    require(msg.sender == withdrawAddress, 'only withdrawer can call this');
    _;
  }
  
  ...
```

This first one's `withdrawFunds` works, but the second doesn't.

The only difference is the `totalBalance` function.

- First example: casts the contract to payable address, and get's it balance
- Second example: uses the `owner` state variable, and get's it balance

The owner variable *is already a payable address*, so I don't understand why the first one succeeds and the second one fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `payable(address(this)).balance` is the amount of Ether held by the contract.

The value of `owner.balance` is the amount of Ether held by the contract's deployer.

Transferring the latter from the contract can work only if it is not larger than the former.

Comment: makes perfect sense!